# Jinja2 translation of links

Tags: google-app-engine, internationalization, template-engine, jinja2

From a Jinja2 template, this is the rendered line I'm after (in English):

```
This is the <a href="roadmap.html">roadmap</a>
```

Translated in Dutch should result in:

```
Dit is de <a href="roadmap.html">planning</a>
```

This Jinja2 line gets me there -almost-

```
{{ _('This is the %(roadmap)s.', roadmap='<a href="roadmap.html">roadmap</a>'|safe) }}
```

Unfortunately, the word 'roadmap' is not translated.

What would be the Jinja2 way of accomplishing this? Splitting the link in roadmap1 and roadmap2? I hope for something more clever.

Comment: This works, but I hope for something more elegant.

`{{ _('This is the %(roadmap)s.', roadmap='<a href="roadmap.html">%s</a>'|safe % _('roadmap')) }}`

Comment: I'm interested to know how you manage to extract strings from your html to a gettext po, for example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should work:

```
{{ _('This is the') }} <a href="roadmap.html">{{ _('roadmap') }}</a>

{{ _('This is the %(roadmap)s', roadmap=('<a href="roadmap.html">%s</a>' % _('roadmap'))|safe) }}
```

Also, if you use webapp2, you might want to replace href="roadmap.html" with e.g. `href="{{ uri_for('roadmap') }}"`

Comment: Nice suggestions indeed. I tried to edit your typo out `_T(` should be `_(`, but SO didn't allow me to modify less than 6 chars.

Comment: ahh, sorry. I don't even recognize where I got _T from. Probably from some other template/language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will get you everything in a single translatable string. You usually don't want the link text ("roadmap") to be a separate translation item.

It works by extracting the opening and closing tag into variables. These must be marked as `safe`, since they contain HTML content that would otherwise be escaped.

```
{% trans link_start='<a href="roadmap.html">'|safe, link_end='</a>'|safe %}
This is the {{ link_start }} roadmap {{ link_end }}.
{% endtrans %}
```