# Using links with babel in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-babel, flask-babel

Currently I'm using Flask and Jinja2 in combination with Babel. So far everything is working great.

The only problem I'm facing is when using links in a translated text. Let's say we have the following in HTML:

```
<p>You can change this in your <a href="{{ url_for("settings") }}">settings</a>.</p>
```

How would I use this in combination with babel?

I had been thinking of the following code, but this gives issues when the order of words is not the same in the translated language.

```
<p>{{ _("You can change this in your ")<a href="{{ url_for("settings") }}">{{ _("settings")</a>.</p>
```

Another idea was to put the entire HTML into the string to be translated but then I cannot use string escaping anymore.

What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: Just an idea: what if you would provide the text in some markdown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jinja2 translation of links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835727/jinja2-translation-of-links)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to this and came across this excellent [page](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiv-i18n-and-l10n).

You can add links by using the string substitution that is available for jinja2 variables.  Here is an example:

```
{{ _("You can change this in your %(open)ssettings%(close)s.", open='<a href="/user/%d">' % user_id, close='</a>')|safe }}
```

Your .po file will then have an entry like this:

```
msgid "You can change this in your %(open)ssettings%(close)s."
msgstr ""
```